# Nav drop down not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

[Here](http://charmcitykids.missionmedia.net/home) I have a nav working perfectly in all browsers but IE.

In IE(any version) when user hovers over 'about us,' 'membership,' 'classes,'  etc.... these words do not change to black text as they should.   It is not swapping out the image.

The javascript that is now in the li was in the a href previously but it needs to be in the li and im thinking a change in the script (im not too skilled with scripts yet) would fix this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which versions of IE have you tried?

Comment: IDK about OP, but for me it worked once in IE8, then I refreshed and now it doesn't work. Silly IE.

Comment: Simplify your dropdown development and use SuperFish (jQuery plugin) at http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Answer (score 1):

The mouseover event doesn't even fire when it gets added to the `<li>`. It fires when it's on the `<a>` inside of the `<li>`. Move the events there. Seems to work without changes to the js too.

Comment: Thank you, but the javascript needs to be in the li.  I had it in the a href before but when user navigated within the drop down the black text(image) went to color image (inactive state); needs to remain black text (image) when user is navigating within each menu.   Thus Im thinking the script needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @Joanah - Hemlock is right..  so without a rewrite of your functions it wont work for the <li> tag... (for the image swap anyways)....  If you just add the onmouseover and onmouseout code to both the <li> and the <a> tags, it will change while over the major group - but not when you sroll down...